# Another Big Nerd Ranch Android Crash error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash

Heres my quizactivity.java my xml's do not have any errors so I will not upload those unless you need it, Please tell me if you do. Also it says that the public void onStart Stop Destroy Resume Ect should be under `} //end onCreate(Bundle)` but I cant find were that is located or if it should even be located in there, is there any way I could search for certain text or phrase within quizactivity.java in the future.

```
 package com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz; 

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "QuizActivity";

    private Button mTrueButton;
    private Button mFalseButton;
    private Button mPrevButton;
    private Button mNextButton;
    private TextView mQuestionTextView;


    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse [] {
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_oceans, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_mideast, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_africa, false),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_americas, true),
        new TrueFalse(R.string.question_asia, true),
    };

    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    private void updateQuestion() {
        int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
    }

    private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
       boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();

       int messageResId = 0;

       if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
           messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
       } else {
           messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;    
       }

       Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
       .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz); 

        mQuestionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

        mTrueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.True_button);
        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);
            }
        });
        mFalseButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false); 
            }
        }); 
        mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button);
        mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();
            }
        });
        mPrevButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prev_button);
        mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 4) % mQuestionBank.length;
                updateQuestion();

            }
        });

                updateQuestion();

            } 

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_quiz, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the LogCat I just copied and pasted the one particular to my package

04-27 22:34:29.026: D/QuizActivity(382): onCreate(Bundle) called
04-27 22:34:29.597: D/AndroidRuntime(382): Shutting down VM
04-27 22:34:29.597: W/dalvikvm(382): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz/com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1748)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1764)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1002)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at com.bignerdranch.android.geoquiz.QuizActivity.onCreate(QuizActivity.java:81)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1712)
04-27 22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382):  ... 11 more
04-27 22:34:39.047: I/Process(382): Sending signal. PID: 382 SIG: 9

Comment: Post the stacktrace. And it is not nerdy...

Comment: real new developer sorry what is the stacktrace also edited code since you responded sorry I messed up first post

Comment: The stacktrace is that long *nerdy* message printed in the log saying that an Exception (or an Error) is thrown. In fact, the stacktrace contains the causes of the error and gives you an idea of how to solve the problem.

Comment: Added Log after just copying and pasting looks odd for me but maybe you will understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luiggi is correct in the comments, the stacktrace provides all the info you need about the error. Particularly this line:

```
22:34:29.617: E/AndroidRuntime(382): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
```

Somewhere in your OnCreate method **you are trying to cast an ImageButton as a Button, this is invalid**. According to the Android Developer Docs, [ImageButton extends ImageView, not Button.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) Thus, a *ClassCastException* is being thrown because you are trying to turn one thing into something that it is not.

Take a look at your **activity_quiz.xml** file and see which view is an ImageButton. You'll need to update its type in your activity to ImageButton to fix this issue.

Good luck with Android Development, it can be pretty fun! :)

Comment: +1. You just missed to say that this is not a nerdy big ranch android crash error :).

Comment: Yeah what happened was they had a challenge to make buttons image buttons by yourself and I forgot to update the script only the xml thanks

Comment: can you also help me with where to place those public void's for onStart onResume onPause etc it says it should be under } //end on create(bundle) but can find that and can I search through the text in there the quizactivity.java for it .